# Installing pypi packages on termux using pip is not working

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi, termux

while installing pyrogram or telethon on termux using pip I facing error. I'll provide error below.

```
~ $ pip install telethon
Collecting telethon                                       Downloading Telethon-1.28.5-py3-none-any.whl (600 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 600.9/600.9   284.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
                    kB
Collecting pyaes (from telethon)
  Downloading pyaes-1.6.1.tar.gz (28 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done            Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      error: [('/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info/PKG-INFO', '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info.__bkp__/PKG-INFO', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info.__bkp__/PKG-INFO'"), ('/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info/dependency_links.txt', '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info.__bkp__/dependency_links.txt', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info.__bkp__/dependency_links.txt'"), ('/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info/top_level.txt', '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info.__bkp__/top_level.txt', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info.__bkp__/top_level.txt'"), ('/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info/SOURCES.txt', '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info.__bkp__/SOURCES.txt', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info.__bkp__/SOURCES.txt'"), ('/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info', '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info.__bkp__', "[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-slc24ohr/pyaes.egg-info.__bkp__'")]
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

how can we solve this problem and install packages correctly on termux

I have tried

```bash
pkg install python-pip
pip install pyrogram
pip3 install pyrogram
MATHLIB="m" pip install pyrogram
```

but all of them useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this issue today and the first thing I got was your question!!

By trying to install it in Venv I could get it to work just fine...!

```bash
mkdir newDir; cd newDir;
python3 -m venv venv
. venv/bin/activate
pip install -U pyrogram
pip install -U telethon
```

bingo

To get outta `venv` just type `deactivate`
hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this installation over a venv or directly in the OS python? This python env are running over Linux or Mac? Because inside of the error message are mentioned some permission issues to manage the files of this package.

Comment: The Q mentions `termux` — it's an android terminal that to some extent emulates Linux but is not actually Linux.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Error appear because `telethon` was installed earlier, and files, which not removed,  disturb to files with same name,
which appearing during installation. Run in `termux` two commands:

`pip uninstall telethon` and... 
`pip install -U telethon`